# Numpy division error

Tags: python, numpy

I get `Numpy Operands could not be broadcast together with shape (200,1,25,25) (200,1)` **error** by the division of two array with the following dimention

```
a=numpy.ones((200,1,25,25))
b=numpy.ones((200,1))
c=a/b
```

**But I can get the right result with the following dimention**

```
a=numpy.ones((4,1,4,4))
b=numpy.ones((4,1))
c=a/b
```

How can I fix the error. My numpy's version is 1.6.1. Python's version is 2.7.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: My question is how to fix the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example doesn't do what you think it does. Numpy matches up axes for broadcasting starting from the right; `(25, 25)` gets matched up with `(200, 1)` in the first example and fails to broadcast, but `(4, 4)` matches up with `(4, 1)` and broadcasts successfully.

Think of a shape-`(200, 1, 25, 25)` array as a 200-by-1 array of 25-by-25 arrays. If you divide this by a 25-by-25 array, numpy will divide every 25-by-25 subarray of the left operand by the right operand. On the other hand, it doesn't make sense to try this with a 200-by-1 divisor. This isn't a complete description of the broadcasting rules - the second example wouldn't have run if this were everything - but it should be enough to start establishing an intuition for how things work.

You may want to reverse the order of your axes:

```
a = numpy.ones((25, 25, 1, 200))
b = numpy.ones((1, 200))
```

It'd probably help to read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for the broadcasting semantics, too.